# JMS Queue testing with spock

Tags: mocking, jms, activemq-classic, spock, geb

I am using activemq and trying to send , whether it is possible to test that if my own created MOCK successfully sent a message to the Queue. I am using Activemq & want to automate the test where, mock send message to queue and with spock you make sure that message has been sent.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Post the code that you are trying to test. Also are you sure your question is related to geb?

Comment: I have already got my answer for this. Thanks for inquiring.

Comment: Perhaps you can put your answer here, so that other people may see it. It might be helpful to others as well.

Comment: I will soon. . I have to validate now ! Thanks

Comment: Scenario was where Mock send message "Good" and get reply as "morning". Defined the primary end point & started the RESTClient in spock, providing appropriate path e.g: uri, params etc . Started the connection of JMS client and set condition to check for string "Good" and asserted the getText for actual string to validate the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first create a QueueBrowser and then using enumeration get the number of messages. Than let a loop run till enumeration object has elements. Than check your message in that loop, if its there. Code should somehow looks like this

```
        QueueBrowser qbrowser = session.createBrowser(QueueName);
        Enumeration messages = qbrowser.getEnumeration();
        while (messages.hasMoreElements())
        {

            TextMessage message = (TextMessage) messages.nextElement();
            String a=message.getText();


            if (Message is there)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Cheers :)